# How to define multiline in tabbing by \newcommand

Tags: tables, macros, environments, texdef

How  to define multiline `tabbing` by `\newcommand` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\not}[2]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2cm}\=\kill
#1\> #2\\
\end{tabbing} 
 }

\begin{document}

\not{$\nabla$}{Gradiant}
\not{$\nabla$}{Gradiant}
\not{$\nabla$}{Gradiant}


\end{document}
```

this is my command:

```
 \documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\not}[2]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2cm}\=\kill
#1\> #2\\
\end{tabbing} 
 }

\begin{document}

\not{$\nabla$}{Gradiant}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't you use a tabular environment?

Answer (score 1):

the error is just from the `\\` after each of your commands in the first example, as the error says, you can not end a line after a tabbing environment as there is no line at that point. Just remove the `\\`, although the use of `tabbing` here seems rather strange, it is not an error.

Comment: the space between two \not{}{} is large

Comment: @HBkhaled well of course it is large, you are putting each line as a separate display but if that was your question why did you not mention it in your question?????

Comment: \hbnot{$\nabla$}{ Gradient Gradien Gradient Gradient Gradient Gradient Gradient Gradientt} new line  !!!! not nice

Comment: @HBkhaled `tabbing` makes single line entries if you want long multiple line entries why are you using `tabbing` ? You have given no indication of the intended use of the command all I can do is say why your original document gave a tex error. almost certainly `tabbing` is not the environment you should be using but without any description of intended input and output impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `\\` after `tabbing`; wrapping it in a `minipage` could be a solution, but you're probably using the wrong tool:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\hbnot}[2]{% <--- don't forget this %
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \hspace{2cm}\=\kill
  #1\> #2\\
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}% <--- don't forget this %
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\hbnot{$\nabla$}{Gradient}\\
\hbnot{$\nabla$}{Gradient}\\
\hbnot{$\nabla$}{Gradient}

\end{document}
```

However, something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\hbnot}[2]{% <--- don't forget this %
  \makebox[2cm][l]{#1}#2% <--- don't forget this %
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\hbnot{$\nabla$}{Gradient}\\
\hbnot{$\nabla$}{Gradient}\\
\hbnot{$\nabla$}{Gradient}

\end{document}
```

is simpler and more efficient.

Note: redefining `\not` is definitely a bad idea. Try using `\not` as in your setup and add the formula

```
$1\neq 2$
```

Maybe you want something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newenvironment{foo}% <--- choose a better name
  {\par\begin{tabbing}\hspace{2cm}\=\kill}
  {\end{tabbing}}

\newcommand{\hbnot}[2]{#1\> #2\\}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X\par % just to check the margins

\begin{foo}
\hbnot{$\nabla$}{Gradient}
\hbnot{$\nabla$}{Gradient}
\hbnot{$\nabla$}{Gradient}
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]